# Interfacing RAM to a DIY computer

Tags: computer-architecture, ram, diy

I am a relatively newbie to electronics but hopefully this question is not very non sensical:

I am following a guide to build a 8 bit computer. The guide requires a RAM which has a 4 address bit and 8 data bits. Unfortunately, the only RAM i have has 8 bit address and 8 bit data. Also, the country I reside in does not have many electronics outlets for these kinds of RAMS. My question is whether I can use the RAM i have instead of the one in the guide by grounding the higher 4 bits to ground? I am thinking by doing so, the higher 4 bits will always be zero and the lower 4 bits can connected to the circuitry of the DIY computer in the same way as demonstrated in the guide?

Thanks.

Comment: Your title states 'ROM' (read only memory), but your question is all about 'RAM'  the rather badly named 'random access memory' - really readable and writeable memory.  ROM is pre-programmed with instructions and data and cannot be changed. RAM can be changed at any time. Just wondered if there was any confusion there?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I meant RAM. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct. Grounding the upper four bits of an 8-bit address bus will effectively convert it to a 4-bit bus; only the first 16 addresses in the RAM will be used.